# Grow/resize RAID when upgrading size of disks

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a server with 8 disks setup with Linux RAID where the boot partitions are RAID1 and the root and partition where I keep VM images are RAID10. I need to replace with larger disk and grow the RAID size putting all the additional space into the partition where I keep VM images. This is the partition setup on each disk:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 480.1 GB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: E2951863-ACAA-4516-A8C0-58FC2098382C


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048    921036799  439.2G  Linux RAID
 2    921036800    934143999    6.3G  Linux RAID
 3    934144000    935194623    513M  Linux RAID
 4    935194624    935604223    200M  Linux RAID
 5    935604224    937701375      1G  Linux RAID
```

I'll be replacing all 8 480GB disks with 960GB disks. As you can see, in this server I have the large partition with my VM images on partition 1, will it be possible for me to replace and grow in this scenario? This is the RAID setup:

```
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid10] [raid1]
md123 : active raid1 sdc4[10] sdb4[9] sde4[8] sdh4[6] sdd4[3] sda4[0] sdg4[5] sdf4[4]
      204736 blocks super 1.0 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md124 : active raid10 sdc1[10] sdb1[9] sde1[8] sdd1[3] sda1[0] sdh1[6] sdg1[5] sdf1[4]
      1841541120 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 8/14 pages [32KB], 65536KB chunk

md125 : active raid1 sdc5[10] sdb5[9] sde5[8] sdf5[4] sdd5[3] sda5[0] sdg5[5] sdh5[6]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid10 sdc2[10] sdb2[9] sde2[8] sdf2[4] sdd2[3] sdh2[6] sdg2[5] sda2[0]
      26193920 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid10 sdc3[10] sdb3[9] sde3[8] sdf3[4] sdh3[6] sda3[0] sdg3[5] sdd3[3]
      2093056 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 near-copies [8/8] [UUUUUUUU]

unused devices: <none>
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md12
md123  md124  md125  md126  md127
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md123
/dev/md123:
           Version : 1.0
     Creation Time : Sun Nov 28 10:07:23 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 204736 (199.94 MiB 209.65 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 204736 (199.94 MiB 209.65 MB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Dec 31 01:00:04 2023
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : boot_efi
              UUID : f0f402f2:cdf1d443:8ef69168:9e61cca3
            Events : 644

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        4        0      active sync   /dev/sda4
       9       8       20        1      active sync   /dev/sdb4
      10       8       36        2      active sync   /dev/sdc4
       3       8       52        3      active sync   /dev/sdd4
       4       8       84        4      active sync   /dev/sdf4
       5       8      100        5      active sync   /dev/sdg4
       6       8      116        6      active sync   /dev/sdh4
       8       8       68        7      active sync   /dev/sde4
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md124
/dev/md124:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Nov 28 10:01:31 2021
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 1841541120 (1756.23 GiB 1885.74 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 460385280 (439.06 GiB 471.43 GB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Jan  6 11:03:14 2024
             State : active
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : vm_images
              UUID : a88079e5:87afdc5a:ace3b41f:11cb43c0
            Events : 280803

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda1
       9       8       17        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb1
      10       8       33        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc1
       3       8       49        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd1
       4       8       81        4      active sync set-A   /dev/sdf1
       5       8       97        5      active sync set-B   /dev/sdg1
       6       8      113        6      active sync set-A   /dev/sdh1
       8       8       65        7      active sync set-B   /dev/sde1
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md125
/dev/md125:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Nov 28 10:07:16 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 1046528 (1022.00 MiB 1071.64 MB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Jan  3 09:46:31 2024
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : boot
              UUID : f2c80fb6:2b15cd8b:0b9968b3:c776c45e
            Events : 726

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        5        0      active sync   /dev/sda5
       9       8       21        1      active sync   /dev/sdb5
      10       8       37        2      active sync   /dev/sdc5
       3       8       53        3      active sync   /dev/sdd5
       4       8       85        4      active sync   /dev/sdf5
       5       8      101        5      active sync   /dev/sdg5
       6       8      117        6      active sync   /dev/sdh5
       8       8       69        7      active sync   /dev/sde5
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md126
/dev/md126:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Nov 28 10:07:07 2021
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 26193920 (24.98 GiB 26.82 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 6548480 (6.25 GiB 6.71 GB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Jan  6 11:10:48 2024
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : root
              UUID : 01f17235:c48db095:1dd7d4c7:6a78beed
            Events : 950594

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        2        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda2
       9       8       18        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb2
      10       8       34        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc2
       3       8       50        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd2
       4       8       82        4      active sync set-A   /dev/sdf2
       5       8       98        5      active sync set-B   /dev/sdg2
       6       8      114        6      active sync set-A   /dev/sdh2
       8       8       66        7      active sync set-B   /dev/sde2
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md12
md123  md124  md125  md126  md127
[root@nebula208-1 ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md127
/dev/md127:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Nov 28 10:07:29 2021
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 2093056 (2044.00 MiB 2143.29 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 523264 (511.00 MiB 535.82 MB)
      Raid Devices : 8
     Total Devices : 8
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat Jan  6 03:07:05 2024
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 8
   Working Devices : 8
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : swap
              UUID : d5dc111a:9935871c:6b7c4333:304a60f3
            Events : 389689

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        3        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sda3
       9       8       19        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb3
      10       8       35        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc3
       3       8       51        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd3
       4       8       83        4      active sync set-A   /dev/sdf3
       5       8       99        5      active sync set-B   /dev/sdg3
       6       8      115        6      active sync set-A   /dev/sdh3
       8       8       67        7      active sync set-B   /dev/sde3
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible…

Comment: Great to know, would I need to rearrange or modify in some way the partition scheme for each disk for all the first partitions to grow, or will mdadm handle growing as I need?

Comment: No, mdadm won't handle the partition scheme for you. If you're used to cloning partition tables with `sfdisk --dump` or similar, that might work for replacing defective drives, but doesn't work when growing.

Comment: I"m not having any issues replacing defective drives with mdadm, I've done this a few times using sgdisk to clone partition layouts from good drives to replacements then inserting with mdadm to rebuild since this server has been in service. I'm only looking at how I could grow the partition 1 RAID in my setup or if I'll have to migrate to a new setup. Thanks for the sfdisk mention, I'll look into using that to solve my quandary. I have a VM setup with the same mdadm scenario for testing.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing. You don't clone partitions when upgrading with larger drives. You partition your new drives, with partitions of desired size, then use those new partitions with mdadm. Your old partition layout does not matter. If you want larger partitions you can do it. If you'd rather have the data partition last instead of first, you can do it. You can replace drives individually, or replace entire set in one go. (Not trying to be unhelpful, I was not sure from your question, if you were simply asking 'will this work?' - yes, or if you were asking for a step-by-step guide)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the insight, I didn't look at it that way. I'll play around with your suggestion in my test VM.